# Redactor - First paragraph always outside of p tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, wysiwyg, redactor

I recently began incorporating redactor(http://redactorjs.com/) into a rails 3.2 app. It's a pretty cool editor, but one issue I keep running into is that the output of the first paragraph - ie as soon as you start typing in the input box - is just inside a div tag or completely without tags rather than a p tag.  Example below... Has anyone else run into this issue? Are there fixes? Also if anyone has any other wysiwig editor suggestions while you're answering this, I'm all ears.

```
<div class="span4 offset2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<span rel="pastemarkerend" id="pastemarkerend20547"></span>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<span rel="pastemarkerend" id="pastemarkerend51485"></span><br>
</p>


</div>
```

Comment: I offered a bounty because I'm interested in solving the paragraph bug. I'm aware of alternatives, but changing the editor is not an option for me right now.

Comment: i did a try and got no problem with it here my code : https://github.com/senayar/try_redactor_js 

Can you provide some code to help you?

Comment: sorry the version before was rails 4, here the rails 3.2 version : https://github.com/senayar/redactor_with_rails3

Comment: I can confirm that in my installation, the initial text *IS* enclosed in a p tag.

Answer (score 2):

don't know if that helps, but I had a remotely similar issue with redactor.js, where all text started as bold (enclosed in a `strong` tag).

Turns out that the CSS I used was somehow influencing the way redactor generated the output. Try to isolate your editor, remove your css or enclose it in another tag, and see what happens...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late but we had a bug with Redactor which occured each time a user copied/pasted text from another web page, i.e. with HTML in it, into the Redactor canvas : we lost random parts of the text due to a completely messed up HTML in the mail that was sent (we use Redactor to write all the mails).

The tag  was always present in the messed up mails so my guess here is that Redactor doesn't handle well the pasting of HTML.

Did you try updating the plugin ?

Answer (score -1):

you can use ckeditor with Rails 3.2, easy to setup.

https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

i did a try with redactor JS and rails 3.2 and i can't reproduce your issue.

https://github.com/senayar/redactor_with_rails3

Can you provide some code to help you ?